# Upstart: cannot run as root

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have made this upstart script, which starts a Node.js service. But all of the sudden the service has stopped, and upstart has failed to restart it. Now that I am trying to start it manually, it fails to recognize my service:

```
start: Unknown job: queue
```

The script is properly placed in `/etc/init`, and should have the correct rights:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  200 Aug  7 13:30 queue.conf
```

When I check the config file with `init-checkconf` however, it says that it is not able to run as root:

```
root@production1:~# init-checkconf /etc/init/queue.conf 
ERROR: cannot run as root
```

What causes this error and how do I solve it?

Debug info:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

root@production1:~# service --version
service ver. 0.91-ubuntu1
```

**Edit**

Here's `queue.conf`:

```
description "Echo.it command queue"
author      "Ronni Egeriis Persson <ronni@echo.it>"

stop on shutdown
respawn
respawn 20 5

exec sudo -u beanstalk /usr/bin/node /var/www/queue/index.js >> /var/log/queue.log 2>&1
```

The command `sudo -u beanstalk /usr/bin/node /var/www/queue/index.js >> /var/log/queue.log 2>&1` works fine when run manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What cannot be run as `root` is `init-checkconf`. Running `init-checkconf` with another user will output the syntax validation to a file in `/tmp`.

In this case the `respawn 20 5` should've been `respawn limit 20 5`.

Comment: Other user gets error: `ERROR: failed to ask Upstart to check conf file`